# Will I need a transit visa to Brazil when I am going to Guyana?

Tags: airport-transfer

I want to know how I can get transit visa to Brazil because am going to Guyana soon...
I am in Nigeria and I also want to know what requirements I need to put in place to get the transit visa from Nigeria to Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

> If traveler intends to pass through immigration, a visa is required. A
>   visa is not required to transit through Brazil as long as the traveler
>   remains in the international transit area, without passing through
>   immigration control. Traveler must be in possession of a valid
>   passport and onward ticket.

Source: [travisa](https://brazil.travisa.com/Common/TVSVisaInstructions.aspx?citizenshipid=ng&countryid=br&residenceid=us&partnerid=ta&glid=aus&travelertypeid=TR)